# How to raise and capture mouse events from a class (Without inheriting from control)?

Tags: c#, wpf, class, mouseevent, polygon

I'm having some trouble with something and I need help!

**My context:**

WPF windows application that displays code-generated polygons on a Virtual Earth 3D map.

**My problem:**

Can't turn the generated polygons into "clickable items".

**Steps taken so far:**

My first approach was to use VE's event attaching pipeline, this does nothing more than "watching" all the events raised over the 3D globe control and returning a list of everything that exists on the location for the click. Although it works, I'm getting an awfull offset at each mouse click, making this approach useless for now.

My second approach was to attach the mouse-click handlers to the polygons. To this effect, I've created this class:

```
  public class ExtendedPolygon:PolygonGeometry
  {

  }
```

That extends the original PolygonGeometry object. Then I've followed advice placed on this thread [giving classes click events C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550200/giving-classes-click-events-c-sharp) to implement the event "listeners" and handlers, like so:

```
public event EventHandler<MouseEventArgs> Click;

protected void OnClick(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler<MouseEventArgs> handler = Click;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

 internal void CheckIfClicked(MouseEventArgs e) 
 {
   OnClick(e);
 }
```

Then (and for the sake of simplicity while testing this), I did all the event attaching on my view's code behind page:

```
polygon.Click +=new EventHandler<MouseEventArgs>(polygon_MouseClick);



void pol_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
            ShowBox(" ShapeId:" + "I clicked");  
    }
```

So, my code runs, polygons get rendered, and yet no click events are raised. Leaving me with the following questions:

-Am I doing this wrong? How should I attach all the pipeline to capture and raise mouse events from a class (that doesn't inherits from control) on WPF?

-Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks for reading and for the time taken with this matter!

PS: If anyone knows a better way to attach events to Virtual Earth Polygons, I'm all ears =)

Comment: Use snoop to see if Click event is fired and if so, is handled by some control up in the visual tree.

Comment: @RFLG, do MouseEtner/MouseLeave work?

Comment: @KaiWang: can you elaborate on that 'Snoop' situation?

Comment: @Dmitry: I haven't tried (thought it would be easier to test with a click), do you have something in mind?

Comment: I think routed events have more chances to work, also I'd try to always use AddHandler in favour of += syntax as that way you can handle handled events too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the code that actually calls CheckIfClicked, in the original post this was done in the OnMouseUp override. Do you have similar code in your app somewhere that wasn't listed in your question?

Comment: Well, sort of...since I have no event to override on WPF (or at least I couldn'd find it), I hooked that check on the Globe Control's OnClick event. Don't know if this is the right way though