# c# wpf add click event to custom class

Tags: c#, wpf, class, events, click

I have searched around and found some things for instance this one [Giving classes click events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550200/giving-classes-click-events-c-sharp) but it does not seem to work for what I want to do or I may have misunderstood how to do it. What I am trying to do is to add a click event to a class called BaseShapes and when the user clicks on the Polygon in BaseShapes, it will execute the click event. Some of the code I have for baseShapes is as follows

```
abstract class BaseShape
{
    public Polygon shape { get; protected set; }
    public event MouseButtonEventHandler MouseDown;

    protected virtual void OnMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MouseDown != null)
        {
            MouseDown(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

I only included the relevant parts, there are way more variables and methods.

In my main window, I added

```
s.MouseDown += test;
```

where s is an instance of BaseShape, of course there is another class that inherits from baseShape. Test just prints a test message to the user. I know I am missing something since it seems like I am not testing whether the user clicked on the shape or not but I am not sure what else to do after this.

The reason why I want to do this instead of just doing s.shape.MouseDown += test; is because I have a method that I want to call when the user has clicked on the shape.  I was thinking about inheriting from UIElements except I have no idea what to do next after this as well =/.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I tried again and after a while I believe I got a way to do this. I think for me the custom events may not be the way I should go about it so instead my BaseShape inherited UIElements and I used OnRender from UIElelements to draw my shape by changing the Polygon to a Geometry and using the parameter that is a DrawingContext to draw the shape.

I then can just draw this shape itself onto my window instead of doing something like this:

```
canvas.Children.Add(s.shape);
```

What I can do now is this:

```
canvas.Children.Add(s);
```

You may wonder why? Well now I do not need any custom events since UIElements comes with all the events I need, mainly click events. I just need to add subscribers. This also allowed me to use the properties within my class instead of having to create a new BaseShape from the Polygon when it is clicked.

I also needed to include these lines to draw the shape in the constructor of my BaseShape class

```
shape.Measure(new Size(length, length));
shape.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, length, length));
```

if not the shape will not be drawn.

If you are wondering what my final code looks like, it is basically this, only the important parts are included:

```
abstract class BaseShape : UIElement
{
    public Polygon shape { get; protected set; }

    public BaseShape()
    {
        shape.Measure(new Size(length, length));
        shape.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, length, length));
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        Geometry s = shape.RenderedGeometry;
        drawingContext.DrawGeometry(Brushes.Red, new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1), s);

        //base.OnRender(drawingContext);
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Shapes.Square sq;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        sq = new Shapes.Square(50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, Brushes.Red, Brushes.Black, Brushes.Red, Brushes.Purple);

        canvas.Children.Add(sq);
        sq.MouseDown += test;
    }

    public void test(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Testing if this works :D");
    }
}
```

}

Hopefully I did not miss a line of code that I changed. I did not need any events within my class but just needed to inherit from UIElements. Still playing around with it but hopefully this is the answer and so far it seems to work :).